# Symfony1.2 is not binding special characters correctly

Tags: php, utf-8, propel, symfony-1.2

I need to insert special characters in Oracle database.

My code:

```
$api_input['forename']='jéíóú';
$stmt->bindParam(':forename',$api_input['forename'], PDO::PARAM_STR | PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 4000);
```

database.yml

```
 dev:
 propel:
  param:
 classname:  DebugPDO
 queries: { value: 'SET NAMES UTF8;' }
 host:       ''
 dsn:        'oci:dbname='
 username:   **
 password:   **
 sessions_db:
 class:        sfPDODatabase
 param:
 classname:  DoctrinePDO
 dsn:        'oci:dbname='
 username:   **
 password:   **
 encoding:   utf8_encode
 collate: utf8_unicode
 charset: utf8
 persistent: false
 pooling:    false
```

But when accessing the same value in Oracle I receive :

> jÃ©Ã­Ã³Ãº

I don't understand if I'm hardcoded value with special characters.

Then how the value is changed when accessing in Oracle procedure.

I have tried all settings but none of solutions work for me.

Why Symfony is changing the input with jÃ©Ã­Ã³Ãº instead of jéíóú?

I have consulted this link: http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/72587/

Comment: In your link, "Finally, someone told me to create a new project with an all new database, and check if accents where working fine --> yes", did you tried this?

Comment: yes sr i  have tried